# JavaScript Amount Of Time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a project that will display the amount of time left in a certain time period based on the users current time. Here is the code.

```js
var periods = [
  [ '07:45' , '08:34' ],
  [ '08:38' , '09:30' ],
  [ '09:34' , '10:23' ],
  [ '10:27' , '11:16' ],
  [ '11:20' , '12:38' ],
  [ '12:42' , '15:55' ],
  [ '07:00' , ]

];


updateTimePeriods();
setInterval(updateTimePeriods, 1000); // Update every second

function updateTimePeriods() {
var listEl = document.getElementById('periods');
  var now = new Date();
  var count = periods.length;
 listEl.innerHTML='';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

   if(formatTimeRemaining(timeLeft(now, periods[i][1])).charAt(0)!='–') {
   child=listEl.appendChild(document.createElement('LI'));
    child.innerHTML = periods[i][0] + ' — ' + periods[i][1]
        + ' => Duration: ' + formatUTCTime(duration(periods[i][0], periods[i][1]))
       + ', Remaining: ' + formatTimeRemaining(timeLeft(now, periods[i][1]));
       
  } 
  
  }
 }
 
 
function duration(start, end) {
  var startTime = parseTime(start);
  var endTime = parseTime(end);
  return endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
}
function timeLeft(now, end) {
  var nowTime = parseTime(formatTime(now));
  var endTime = parseTime(end);
  return endTime.getTime() - nowTime.getTime();
}
function parseTime(timeStr) {
  var tokens = timeStr.split(':');
  return new Date(1970, 0, 1, parseInt(tokens[0], 10), parseInt(tokens[1], 10));
}
function formatUTCTime(time) {
  var date = new Date(time);
  return padZero(date.getUTCHours()) + ':' + padZero(date.getUTCMinutes());
}
function formatTime(time) {
  var date = new Date(time);
  return padZero(date.getHours()) + ':' + padZero(date.getMinutes());
}
function formatTimeRemaining(time) {
  var sign = '+';
  if (time < 0) { time *= -1; sign = '–'; }
  var date = new Date(time);
  return sign + padZero(date.getUTCHours()) + ':' + padZero(date.getUTCMinutes())  + ':' + padZero(date.getUTCSeconds());
}
function padZero(n) { return ('00' + n).substr(-2); }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #A00000;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer-box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: true;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
#periods {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <ul id="periods"></ul>
</div>
```

My goal is only display to the user the amount of time left in the current time period instead of all of them. And if its in between a time period it shows the amount of time until the next one occurs. The issue is once all the times occur I need to tell him much time until the start of the next time which occurs on a different day. To elaborate, currently if all the time periods occur it displays a blank space because there is nothing to display and all the times are negative. I want to display the amount of time until the next days starting time.

Comment: All you need is someone will do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You should break the for loop as you create the new LI element. This way it should only show the actual time period.

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
 if(formatTimeRemaining(timeLeft(now, periods[i][1])).charAt(0)!='–') {
  child=listEl.appendChild(document.createElement('LI'));
  child.innerHTML = periods[i][0] + ' — ' + periods[i][1]
     + ' => Duration: ' + formatUTCTime(duration(periods[i][0], periods[i][1]))
     + ', Remaining: ' + formatTimeRemaining(timeLeft(now, periods[i][1]));
  break;  
 }
}
```